# Transit visa for 2 layovers

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, layovers, uae, istanbul

I am an Indian citizen traveling from Delhi to Milan with layovers in Sharjah and Istanbul. Do I need transit visas for both Sharjah and Istanbul airports? The airline are different from Delhi to Sharjah and thereafter.

Comment: What countries are Sharjah and Istanbul in?

Comment: You will need a visa from *every country* where you transit if your citizenship does not qualify you for visa-free transit in those countries and/or you do not hold any other travel document that would make you eligible for TWOV. You can find out by entering the full details of your itinerary and travel document(s) in the IATA Travel Centre website https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/

Comment: Are the flights booked separately (different tickets) or are they on a single ticket?

Comment: @djclayworth sharjah is Dubai and Istambul is Turkey

Comment: @jcaron I booked the flight from edreams. I think they have different tickets.

Comment: @AnjaliKashyap: you MUST check whether this is a single ticket or not as it makes a huge difference, Check ticket numbers and PNR (passenger name records). Most reputable OTA (online travel agencies) don't sell separate tickets but others (like Kiwi) do. These are really bad ideas unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Because both the stops are in different countries, you potentially need a transit visa for each of them. Check for each individual country whether you specifically require a transit visa for that country.